# memory allocated inside a c++ function

Tags: c++

My question is: Doesn't the memory allocated inside a function deallocate by default when exiting the function?

For example:

```
double* calc(int res_size, int max)
{
    double*    p = new double[max];
    double   res = new double[res_size] ;

    // use p to calculate results to be put in res

    return res;
 }
```

Are we leaking memory for the rest of the program?

Comment: If the memory pointed by `res` would be automatically deallocated, what would you expect to happen when you return `res`?

Comment: So, you mean that if we don't specifically "delete[]" the memory allocated in the function is unusable for whole program?

Comment: Yes, if you don't `delete[]` the memory allocated for `p` then you have a memory leak. Also if you don't `delete[]` the returned pointer. However, is there really a need to dynamically allocate memory like that? Can't you use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead?

Comment: Technically speaking the leak only happens once you lose any pointer to the memory and then by definition you have no way of de-allocating it. Up until that point it's just allocated, not leaked.

Comment: Alright, I understand. Do not confuse stack space and heap space. Local variables are stored in stack space and they are lost when exiting the function. The space allocated in the heap is used and marked as used when allocated. To use this heap space allocated we use the pointers. This pointer (local variable in a function) if not returned is lost (as it is kept in stack space) but the memory allocated for it remains marked as "used".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `p` is leaked after you lose scope and I assume you meant `double* res` rather than `double res` - if so, that should be OK since you're passing it back on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `p` is leaked in your case. You might want to try this:

```
double* calc(int res_size, int max)
{
    double*    p = new double[max];
    double*   res = new double[res_size] ;

    // use p to calculate results to be put in res

    delete[] p;
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't the memory allocated inside a function deallocate by default when exiting the function?

Yes, if you employ proper RAII wrappers to manage memory/resources, like so

```
#include <memory>

double* calc(int res_size, int max)
{
   std::unique_ptr<double[]> p(new double[max]);
   std::unique_ptr<double[]> res(new double[res_size]);

   // use p to calculate results to be put in res

   return res.release();
   // we're not leaking p, it'll get deleted on function exit
   // we're returning res, which should be managed by the caller accordingly
}
```

> Are we leaking memory for the rest of the program?

Yes, for the function you've posted; no, for the above one.